# Re-encoding mkv video (HEVC) to make it working in a LG CX smart TV

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc

My LG CX TV can't play some mkv videos even if the codec (HEVC) is supported and working fine with other videos.

I would like to copy the same settings from a working video and re-encode the "non working" one  using ffmpeg.

How can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: This is actually many questions in one, once you start digging a bit. Maybe "re-muxing" (changing container (options)) is what you want to do, if your movie really has the right codec (parameters). But maybe your dimensions are not supported... So, you need to find out, what formats your TV supports, and compare the specs with the output of `mediainfo` or `ffprobe -i` with working and non-working files. Post the media-info output of your desired file. Maybe something obvious becomes visible

Comment: @AlexStragies
NON working video:

Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 1920x818, SAR 1:1 DAR 960:409, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default) (forced) 

Working video:


Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/smpte2084), 1920x804, SAR 1:1 DAR 160:67, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)

Comment: maybe is the audio the problem:  
  
non working video: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s (default)  
  
working video:  
  
Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 640 kb/s

Comment: Update your question with the additional data, do not put it in comments

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx265 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -c:a ac3  output.mkv
```

input video:

```
hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 1920x818, SAR 1:1 DAR 960:409, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default) (forced)
```

input audio:

```
ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s (default)
```

output video:

```
hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv, progressive), 1920x818 [SAR 1:1 DAR 960:409], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default) (forced)
```

output audio:

```
ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s (default)
```

So the problem is the pixel format.